# How to Install AWS Public SSL on AWS EC2 Instance a WordPress Site

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS wordpress instance that has a domain pointed to it. Now I want to install the free public SSL aws offered. So I created an HTTPS/SSL Load Balancer. After working on it the certificate updated the "in use" column to Yes (http://prntscr.com/nimdop). I accessed my site but its still not directing to https. Can someone tell me what I missed? or give some documentation on how to use this public ssl aws issues?

Comment: If you manually type in https in your browser do you get to the site correctly?

Comment: Did you point your domain to the load balancer, or is it still pointing directly to the EC2 server?

Comment: i get this error "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

http://prntscr.com/niy4d3

Comment: i did not change the A record http://prntscr.com/niy53g

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have ACM certificate on your Load balancer, you need to configure a redirection rule on ALB to redirect your requests to https.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#redirect-actions

Comment: Hi James,
Sorry I'm still new to AWS platform. Where do I access the redirect options? 
btw I followed the documentation on creating an https listener.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html. Screenshot http://prntscr.com/niy5xv. Is it correct?